# instantiating an object at a specific position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

been trying to do this for the past hour here is the code I have so far

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;



public class clone : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject fruit;
    void Update()
    {
        Instantiate(fruit);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not much for one hour .... Have you tried/researched anything at all?maybe you should go through some very basic Unity tutorials before doing anything further

Comment: Clearly state what you are trying to do and what errors you get. Also check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple overloads of Instantiate [documented](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) and it even returns the GameObject, so you can manipulate the position.

Either:

```
Instantiate(fruit, new Vector3(1,2,3), Quaternion.Identity);
```

or:

```
GameObject obj = Instantiate(fruit);
obj.transform.position = new Vector3(1,2,3);
```

Note: Your code spawns objects **every frame** as it's in `Update()` - you should do in in a function that is triggered by a KeyPress or do it in `Start` which is called once in the beginning. You could use a loop if you need multiple fruits.

Comment: GameObjects don't have a position property. I think you mean obj.transform.position in your second part of the code.